# How to be sure that Android application will work on every device

Tags: android, testing

I have a beta application, which runs successfully on three Android powered devices: 
Google Nexus One, Nexus S, and Motorola Defy+.

How can I be sure that it will work on every single Android device with android 2.3+?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Own testing**

You can be 100% sure when you have tested it on each phone. Of course that is very impractical in reality. So, I would follow these steps to make sure app works with different resolutions, manufactures, and phones vs tablets:

1. Test with phones with different *resolutions*: small, medium, high, and very high.
2. Test with a *tablet*
3. Test with *major manufacturers* and those dear to you: Google, HTC, LG, Motorola, Samsung...
4. Release into market

You would need about 5-10 phones/tablets. Finally, just release into market. Then follow closely crash reports and user feedback.

**User Test Sessions**

You could arrange test sessions with users. Preferably after your own tests and before releasing into the Android Market:

1. Invite 5-20 people with their own Android phones.
2. Observe and take notes
3. Ask feedback
4. Repeat with another group if necessary

**Automated Testing**

Testing with automated scripts or against devices in cloud are also good options. Thanks CommonsWare for the tip. Here are some vendors to start with:

TestDroid: http://testdroid.com
LessPainful: https://www.lesspainful.com/
Experitest: http://experitest.com/?gclid=CJP-uI7bxawCFcQXzQodrXsopw
Apkudo: http://www.apkudo.com/

Comment: You might also look into automated multi-device test services like LessPainful, TestDroid Cloud, and apkudo.